# Minimum and maximum sums from a list Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I've been doing problems on HackerRank to get my foot in the door for solving Python problems and while I've had fun working through a few, one problem is stumping me.

This problem is the Mini-Max sum, which takes an input(**arr**); an array of **5 integers**, and prints the sum of the biggest and smallest 4 integers from arr in the next line's format via **miniMaxSum(arr)**

maximum minimum

e.g. miniMaxSum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

10 14

I've done something which you can find below that works with this, and **most examples** to return the desired results, but I've just found out that it doesn't work for arr = (5, 5, 5, 5, 5). I suspect that this is because when the maximum value is identical to another value in the list (e.g. arr = 1, 2, 3, 4, 4) or likewise for minimum (e.g. arr = 1, 1, 3, 4, 5), my code simply fails as it **relies on nothing being the same as arr's biggest or smallest value**. The HackerRank error message is "**Wrong Answer**" if that helps.

Please **critique and suggest improvements** so it works with **any** array of 5 integers (e.g. (5, 5, 5, 5, 5)). I am keen in understanding how this works and your help would be immensely appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
# Complete the miniMaxSum function below.
def miniMaxSum(arr):
    listmax = []
    listmin = []
    for number in arr:
        if number > min(arr):
            listmax.append(number)    
    for number in arr:
        if number < max(arr):
            listmin.append(number)
    maxnum = sum(listmax)
    minnum = sum(listmin)
    print (minnum, maxnum)
```

Comment: Are you forgetting to mention that the goal is to add **4** out of the **5** numbers? [reference](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mini-max-sum/problem)?

Comment: An easy solution might be to first `sort` the input. The `min` will be the sum of the first four numbers, the `max` will be the sum of the last four numbers.

Comment: If the code works, this probably belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi @user633183, you are correct, and I've edited the Question to say that the sum displayed is of the biggest and lowest 4 numbers. And thank you so much for the solution! It worked :)

Comment: Hey @Alexander, my apologies; I just made my account today so I assumed this was the place to put it. You're welcome to move  this question there if it fits the website best

Answer (score 9):

Since it's a really small list, I would just sort it and then pick off the first-5 and then the last 5 and take the sums of those, respectively.

```
def miniMaxSum(arr):
  arr_sorted = sorted(arr)
  return sum(arr_sorted[:4]), sum(arr_sorted[-4:])

print(miniMaxSum([1,2,3,4,5]))
print(miniMaxSum([5,5,5,5,5]))
```

Output:

```
>>> print(miniMaxSum([1,2,3,4,5]))
(10, 14)
>>> print(miniMaxSum([5,5,5,5,5]))
(20, 20)
```

Comment: Thank you @booleys1012! This method works perfectly :)

Answer (score 5):

Try taking the overall sum and subtracting minimum or maximum:

```
def maxnum (x):
    return sum(x) - min(x)
def minnum(x):
    return sum(x) - max(x)

a = list(range(5))
b = [5]*5
print (a)
print (maxnum(a), minnum(a))
print (b)
print (maxnum(b), minnum(b))
```

output:

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

10 6

[5, 5, 5, 5, 5]

20 20

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/python3
# Complete the miniMaxSum function below.
def miniMaxSum(arr):
   arr=sorted(arr)
   s = sum(arr)
   print(s-arr[-1],s-arr[0])
```

Comment: `arr[len(arr)-1] == arr[-1]`

Answer (score 1):

It's not working with edge case arrays, say [5,5,5,5,5] because in when the program tries to pick out the 'listmax' and 'listmin', the program finds itself in a unique position where 'number' is neither greater than nor less than the max(arr). you can try to add a condition when each index is compared with the max so you don't miss out on repetitions of max/min values.

I went for computing all the sums and then choosing the min and max. Hope you find the code below helpful :

```
 def miniMaxSum(arr):
        sum_all = [] #list of sums of all the 4 elements
        temp = arr
        for i in range(5):
            p = temp.pop(i) #popping out an element to get an array of 4 elements 
            sum_all.append(sum(temp)) #calculating sum of all 4 elements
            temp.insert(i,p) #reset the list
        s_max = max(sum_all)
        s_min = min(sum_all)
        print(s_min , s_max) #prints the min and max of all the sums
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution will be convenient for all test cases of the problem.
 so, please try it out and run.

```
def miniMaxSum(arr):

    max_elem = max(arr)
    min_elem = min(arr)

    mini = arr.copy()
    mini.remove(max_elem)

    maxi = arr.copy()
    maxi.remove(min_elem)

    sum_min = sum(mini)
    sum_max = sum(maxi)

    print(sum_min, sum_max)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
    miniMaxSum(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

pure logic -

```
def miniMaxSum(arr):
    sums=[]
    s=0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        for j in range(len(arr)):
            s += arr[j] # suming all
        s = s-arr[i]
# remove current position value because u need sum of (size-1)
        sums.append(s)
        s=0
    low=high=sums[1] #assign first value for comparison
    for i in range(len(sums)):
        if low > sums[i]:
            low = sums[i]
        if high < sums[i]:
            high =sums[i]
    print(low,high)
```

I don't use keyword like short,sum. All test case done,Answer-

```
Test case 0
Test case 1
Test case 2
Test case 3
Test case 4
Test case 5
Test case 6
Test case 7
Test case 8
Test case 9
Test case 10
Test case 11
Test case 12
Test case 13
Test case 14
Compiler Message
Success
Input (stdin)

1 2 3 4 5
Expected Output

10 14
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def minmax(n):
    a = sorted(n)
    mini = 0
    max = 0
    ll = len(n)
    for i in range(ll-1):
        max += n[i]
        mini += n[i+1]
    print(mini, max)
    
#  Driver Code
arr = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
arr1 = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
    
minmax(arr)
minmax(arr1)
```

Answer (score 0):

this would be easier

```
 arr = [5,5,5,5,5]
def miniMaxSum(arr):
    sum = 0
    for number in range(len(arr)):
        sum = sum +  arr[number]
    print (sum-max(arr), sum-min(arr))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
def miniMaxSum(arr):
    sorted_list = sorted(arr)
    print(sum(sorted_list[0:len(arr)-1]),sum(sorted_list[1:len(arr)]))
```

Answer (score -1):

I like Ruslan's idea of finding the sum then subtracting the min or max to get each answer. However, instead of using 3 loops (one for sum, one for min, and one for max) we can do it all in one loop -

```
from math import inf

def minimum (a, b):
  return a if a < b else b

def maximum (a, b):
  return a if a > b else b

def minmaxsum (*xs):
  min = inf
  max = -inf
  sum = 0
  for x in xs:
    min = minimum (min, x)
    max = maximum (max, x)
    sum = sum + x
  return (sum - max, sum - min)

print (minmaxsum (1, 3, 5, 7, 9))
# (16, 24)

print (minmaxsum (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
# (10, 14)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def miniMaxSum(a):   
    max = sum(list(filter(lambda x: x<max(a) if a.count(max(a))==1 else x<=max(a),a)))
    min = sum(list(filter(lambda x: x>min(a) if a.count(min(a))==1 else x>=min(a),a)))
    print(min,max)
```

This may help, and if not, can you update your expected output when your input is [1,1,2,3,4] or [1,2,3,4,4] or [5,5,5,5,5] ?